# Performance when shipping logs from PHP to AWS ElasticSearch/OpenSearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Is it recommended to ship logs directly from a PHP app to ElasticSearch? Or is it always better to store to file and use filebeat to ship the logs? I'm familiar with C# and Serilog implementation sending directly to ES and we've never had an issue with it, but was wondering if the same could be done with a PHP app using Monolog without performance being severely impacted. I'm assuming Serilog is able to asynchronously send the logs, I'm not sure if the Monolog implementation on PHP is able to do that or if it would only be OK to ship directly as long as they're infrequent error logs but info/debug logging would cripple performance. Anybody have any experience doing this? For additional background, we'd be using AWS OpenSearch and the PHP app would also be running at AWS in ECS/Fargate containers, so it would be inside the same network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

personally I would recommend logging to a file and then shipping, no matter the end datastore you end up chosing

the reason is that otherwise you need to handle a tonne of logic in your client - load balancing/failover, retries, error handling, back pressure - and while another client library for that datastore may abstract some of this out, it's probably not the best place for it

the biggest issue there would be back pressure. what happens if something happens that delays, or stops, logging to your datastore? do you keep the log in memory and retry later? do you block till the log is stored? how do you manage those aspects

if you log to a file (or even stdout for containers) you have a pretty clear delineation point for your code. you will likely have a backup of the log incase you ever need to check it, and you can use task specific tooling to ship your logs

Comment: also as an aside, opensearch is not Elasticsearch. it's an aws run fork

Comment: So in a Fargate scenario, you'd recommend saving to a file on the container (assuming it's ephemeral but we're shipping so should be OK most of the time). And then would filebeat be running in its own container with the ability to access the files on the other container or run filebeat on each container since it's pretty lightweight?

Comment: or put it into stdout and let Filebeat read that, yes

Comment: So if you write to a file, I assume you need to also ensure you have some process running to clean up the file so you don't run out of space on the container?

Comment: logrotate is pretty standard there